# Is the symbol for set membership $\in$ derived from greek letter $\epsilon$?

Tags: mathematics, notation

Title self explains: Is the symbol for set membership $\in$ derived from greek letter $\epsilon$? What is their historical relationship? Obviously the letter must be older, since greek alphabet is extremely old. 
Paul Halmos Naive Set theory, page 2, second paragraph (equivalently page 2 lines 8-11)

> This version of the Greek letter epsilon is so often used to denote
>   belonging that its use to denote anything else is almost prohibited.
>   Most authors relegate $\in$ to its set-theoretic use forever and use $\epsilon$
>   when they need the fifth letter of the Greek alphabet.

In the comments of [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/176783/what-does-the-letter-epsilon-signify-in-mathematics/176784#176784) is found a discussion, but not in the form of answer. Also this site seems more appropriate than Math.SE.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes and no. Peano originally used $\epsilon$ in *Arithmetices Prinicipia Nova Methodo Exposita* (1889), and stated that the symbol was an abbreviation for Latin *est* (is), apparently using a Greek letter for a Latin word. However, as Mauro Allegranza pointed out, in *Principi di Logica Matematica* (1891) he changes the script, and explains the use of $\varepsilon$ by reference to the Greek *ἐστι* (is). In *Formulaire de Mathematiques* (1895) Peano goes back to $\epsilon$ (possibly the choice between the two depended on typographers).

In the first edition of *Principia Mathematica* (1903) Russell explicitly adopted Peano’s symbol $\varepsilon$, along with the Greek lineage. Extensional (sets) and intensional (classes) notions were not separated at the time, so Russell-Peano's $a\,\varepsilon P$ is more of intensional "$a$ is $P$", with $P$ as a class defining property, than modern extensional "$a$ is an element of the set $P$". Fully extensional interpretation of sets only appears in Hausdorff's Grundzuge der Mengenlehre (1914), see [Kanamori's The empty set, the singleton, and the ordered pair](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.95.9839&rep=rep1&type=pdf). The stylized $\in$ and its crossed version $\not\in$ appear in Bourbaki's Theorie des Ensembles (1939), likely responsible for their widespread adoption, but they might have been used earlier.

See [Jeff Miller's site Earliest Uses of Symbols of Set Theory and Logic](http://jeff560.tripod.com/set.html) and [Cajori's History of Mathematical Notations](https://books.google.com/books?id=bT5suOONXlgC&source=gbs_navlinks_s) for these and similar questions.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Sorry, I do not follow. It is written in Latin, but he uses Greek letters.

Comment: He does **not** say that the Greek symbol $\varepsilon$ is an abbreviation for the Latin word "*est*" (is); he says that the Greek symbol $\varepsilon$ is an abbreviation for the Greek word "*ἐστι*" (is). At that time every learned man (mathematician included), especially in "latin" european countries, studied Latin **and** Ancient Greek and thus they were perfectly able to "do **not** mix Greek and Latin" :-)

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I see now, Jeff Miller's entry only accounts for Arithmetices Prinicipia version, I should have checked. I cleaned it up.

Answer (score 17):

Yes, it is.

In [Giuseppe Peano](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Giuseppe_Peano)'s [*Arithmetices Principia*](https://archive.org/stream/arithmeticespri00peangoog#page/n16/mode/2up) (1889), the $\epsilon$ symbol is explained as follows (page x):

> Signum $\epsilon$ significat *est*.
>
> > [The sign $\epsilon$ means *is*.]

In his [*Principi di Logica matematica*](https://books.google.it/books?hl=it&id=MyxPAAAAYAAJ&dq=peano+logica+matematica&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=%288%29) (1891), Peano gives the full explanation (page 3) :

> Per indicare la proposizione singolare « $x$ è un individuo della classe $s$ » scriveremo (<sup>8</sup>)
>   [To mean the proposition "$x$ is an individual of the class $s$" we will write]
>   $$x \varepsilon s,$$
>
> e il segno $\varepsilon$  si potrà leggere [*è*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/essere#Italian), o *è un*, o *fu*, o *sarà*, a seconda delle regole grammaticali; però il suo significato è sempre quello spiegato.
>   [and the sign $\varepsilon$ will be read *is*, or *is a*, ...]
>
> [...]
>
> (<sup>8</sup>): Il segno $\varepsilon$ è l'iniziale di [*ἐστι*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E1%BC%94%CF%83%CF%84%CE%B9%CE%BD).
>   [The sign $\varepsilon$ is the initial of *ἐστι*.]

See also: Hubert Kenendy, [What Russell learned from Peano](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ndjfl/1093891001), NDJFL (1973).

And see: Alfred North Whitehead and Bertrand Russell, [*Principia Mathematica*](https://books.google.it/books?id=ke9yGmFy24sC&pg=PA25) (1910-1913), page 25:

> The propositional function "$x$ is a member of the class $\alpha$" will be expressed, following Peano, by the notation
>
> $$x \epsilon \alpha.$$
>   Here $\epsilon$ is chosen as the initial of the word *ἐστι*.

In 1888, [Richard Dedekind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richard_Dedekind), in [*Was Sind und was Sollen Die Zahlen?*](https://books.google.it/books?id=TK3OpvuABOMC&pg=PA2) (art. 3), used a "reversed" $\varepsilon$ ($A ∋ S$) to mean "is part of", where this relation slid between membership and improper inclusion.