# Why is the existential quantifier symbol ∃ a backwards "E"?

Tags: terminology, notation, mathematical-logic, logic

Peano introduced a number of logical symbols still used today:

- $∨$ (from Latin ***v***el)
- $∧$ (inverted $∨$)
- $∃$

This inversion of Latin letters as symbols (and inversion of symbols to signify their 'opposite' operation) was followed by later logicians:

- $∀$ (Gentzen, [1935](https://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/id/PPN266833020_0039?tify=%7B%22pages%22:%5B184%5D%7D): inverted A from *"**A**ll-Zeichen" / "Für **A**lle"*, by analogy to $∃$)
- $⊥$ (inverted $⊤$)

I had always assumed that ∃ stood for "E" in ***"E***xistential" / "there **E**xists" (or some cognate thereof), but Peano did not appear to use any words beginning 'e' in the paragraph this symbol was introduced:

> Mais nous préférons l'indiquer par la nouvelle notation
>
> $$Ǝa$$
>
> qu'on peut lire « il y a des $a$ ».
>
> - [*Formulaire de mathématiques*](https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k84142s/f48.item), Peano (1897)

**So why did he choose an inverted "E"?**

---

<sup>[*Earliest Uses of Symbols of Set Theory and Logic*](http://jeff560.tripod.com/set.html)</sup>
<sup>[Is the symbol for set membership $\in$ derived from greek letter $\epsilon$?](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/q/5817/55)</sup>
<sup>[Math SE: What came first, the ∀ or the ∃?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1183278/what-came-first-the-forall-or-the-exists)</sup>

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106853/discussion-on-question-by-ukemi-why-is-the-existential-quantifier-symbol--a-bac).

Comment: According to [Jeff Millers page](http://jeff560.tripod.com/set.html) it was Russel and Heyting who introduced $\wedge$ and $\vee$. Could you add sources to your claim that it was Peano?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When introducing the older terminology in the previous sentence, Peano describes it thus:

> ... signifie "il y a des *a*", "les *a* **e**xistent"...

It seems likely this is the source of the inverted "E".